# Parametric Polymorphism Problem: Using function with single float parameter with an array of float parameters

Tags: python, function, parametric-polymorphism, simulated-annealing

To clarify what I mean, my issue is with a simulated annealing problem where I want to find the theta that gives me the max area of a shape:

```
def Area(theta):
    #returns area
def SimAnneal(space,func, T):
    #space is some linspace
    #func is some function that takes in some theta and outputs some area
    #T = separate temperature parameter that is not relevant for problem
    #returns maximum area from given thetas
```

Simulated annealing starts by choosing a random starting “theta”, in this scenario. My goal is to use the setup above as shown below. It should be noted that the input for area() is a single theta, but my hope was that there was some way to make ? a “potential” list of thetas that the next function, SimAnneal(), can choose from.

```
  x = np.linspace(0,100,1000)
  func = area(?)
  T = 4
  SimAnneal(x,func,T)
```

What should I put into ? in order for SimAnneal to output correctly.

***In other words, is there a ? that can satisfy the condition of being a single float parameter but carry all the possible float parameters in some linspace?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`np.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) to apply a `func` taking a single value as follows:

```
import numpy as np

def Area(theta):
    pass

def SimAnneal(space, func, T):
    applied_space = np.vectorize(func)(space)

x = np.linspace(0, 100, 1000)
T = 4
SimAnneal(x, Area, T)
```

Note that `np.vectorize` won't actually give you performance improvements that we see with actual vectorization. It is instead a convenient interface that exactly fits your need: Applying a `func` that takes a single value to a bunch of values (your `space`).

Alternative, you can move the `np.vectorize` call outside of `SimAnneal` like this:

```
def SimAnneal(space, func, T):
    applied_space = func(space)

x = np.linspace(0, 100, 1000)
func = np.vectorize(Area)
T = 4
SimAnneal(x, func, T)
```

This is closer to your original example.

Answer (score -1):

First, there is no data type that is both a float and a collection. Additionally, you want to pass the area function directly into the `SimAnneal` function rather than the return of a call to it as you currently have it:

```py
SimAnneal(x, area, T)
```

From a design standpoint, it would make more sense to leave the `area` function as is taking a single float as a parameter. That being said, it is relatively simple to run a single function through a list and store those outputs with the theta that created it using a technique called [Dictionary Comprehensions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary-comprehension/). In the example below `thetas` is the list of thetas you want to choose from:

```py
areas = {i: area(i) for i in thetas}
```

From there you can then search through the new dictionary to find the theta that produced the greatest area:

```py
max_theta = list(areas.keys())[0] # retrieve the first theta

for theta, area in areas.items():
    if area > areas[theta]:
        max_theta = theta

return theta
```